# import scalaz monad syntax outside of function

Tags: scala, scalaz

Is there a way I can avoid importing monad syntax in the body of all my functions? Here's what I'm stuck writing:

```
object Example {
  def doMonadThings[M[_]: Monad, A](ma: M[A]): M[A] = {
    val monadSyntax = implicitly[MonadSyntax[M]]
    import monadSyntax._

    ma.flatMap { x => point(x) }
  }
}
```

`scalaz 7.2`

EDIT:

Here's what I ended up with:

```
object Example {
  import scalaz.syntax.monad._

  def doMonadThings[M[_], A](ma: M[A])(implicit m: Monad[M]): M[A] =
    ma.flatMap { x => m.point(x) }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
import scalaz.syntax.monad._

def doMonadThings[M[_]: Monad, A](ma: M[A]): M[A] = {
  ma.flatMap[A] { x => x.point }
}
```

Comment: This gets all the methods, but doesn't get functions like `point`.

Comment: oh wait I see what you did there. it's kind of weird to have `point` implicitly on everything but yes this does solve my problem.

Comment: @codenoodle Otherwise you can avoid syntax: `val m = Monad[M]`
    `m.bind(ma){ x => m.point(x) }`

Comment: Or `val m = Monad[M]`
    `import m._`
    `bind(ma){ x => point(x) }`

Comment: Ahh that gives me an idea. I'm going to update the question with what I landed on.  Thanks for the help.